# Propagating focus event from custom form control to Angular reactive form

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, tinymce, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form setup in an Angular 4 app that has a mix of regular form controls and some custom controls that implement the TinyMCE editor.

It's all setup and working OK for writing changes from the HTML text areas back to the reactive form controls (and this also allows for validation rules to be applied correctly). However I now have a requirement to listen for focus events to update a filter.

This is working for the 'regular' form controls however the TinyMCE custom controls are proving a bit of a problem.  This is the code I have for the TinyMCE custom control:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  tinymce.init({
    selector: '#' + this.elementId,
    plugins: ['lists', 'charactercount'],
    skin_url: '/assets/skins/lightgray',
    menubar: false,
    branding: false,
    height: 150,
    setup: (editor) => {
      this.editor = editor;
      editor.on('keyup click', () => {
        const content = editor.getContent();
        this.propagateChange(content);
      });
      editor.on('focusin', (ev) => {
        console.log(ev);
      });
    },
  });
}

propagateChange = (_: any): void => { }

registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
  this.propagateChange = fn;
}

registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
  this.propagateChange = fn;
}
```

As you can see the event object is being logged to the console (and this does show up when I focus on one of the TinyMCE form controls).  The problem is this doesn't seemed to be recognised in the Angular parent component which is using a `@HostListener`

```
@HostListener('focusin', ['$event']) updateFilter(event: any) {
  this.commentFilterField.value = event.srcElement.id;
}
```

I've tried adding `this.propagateChange(ev);` and similar to the `focusin` event, trying to manually force the firing of the TinyMCE `focus()` event and also trying to update the reactive form state using `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` listener but no joy.

Comment: not sure why HostListener isn't working maybe it only listens to native events? But what you could do is in the tinymce focusin function you could just dispatch another event instead of trying to use focusin.

Comment: Yep, awesome thanks for your suggestion.  I added an `EventEmitter` and passed the event to this when the TinyMCE control receives focus.